# Is the word "processing" a gerund in this sentence?

Tags: gerunds

Is the word "processing" a gerund in this sentence?

> Women also had to shoulder the responsibility for new labor-intensive tasks, **processing** the secondary products of larger herds.

Source: "[Ancient Greece from Prehistoric to Hellenistic Times](https://brewminate.com/a-background-to-the-history-of-ancient-greece/)" by Thomas R. Martin

Answer (score 1):

The source has a comma before "processing".

This makes "processing the secondary products of larger herds" a gerund-participle phrase in apposition to "tasks".  (Most modern grammars don't distinguish between gerunds and present participles).

It is a gerund-participle (and not a noun) because it has a direct object, and an implicit subject (women).